# How to handle wait and response in servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, chat

I am working on an android based chat application to experiment with client-server, cloud technologies. 
I have created a client to send and receive http messages using Apache Http Components.
I used Servlets to process and respond to requests.

Now, I am sending message from **from_user** to **to_user**.
I am able to send a message from **from_user** to server using http POST.
Now, problem is how to forward the message to the intended **to_user**?

For this, I am trying to use push based mechanism specified for BOSH-XMPP standard.

According to wikipedia:

> For "push", a BOSH client starts an HTTP request, but the server
>   postpones sending a reply until it has data to send.[1] After
>   receiving a reply, the client immediately makes another request on the
>   same HTTP connection, so the server can always send data to the client
>   without waiting for the client to poll. If while waiting for a reply
>   the client needs to send data to the server, it opens a second HTTP
>   connection. There are at most two HTTP connections open at a time, one
>   on which the server can send data as a reply and one on which the
>   client can send data as a POST.

Since I am using servlets, how to introduce wait and response in servlets?
Also am I on right track w.r.to using of servlets for chat server?

Please suggest in this regard.

Comment: Explore Web Sockets server (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html), client (http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-websocket-client-api.html). A good fit for your kind of application

Comment: Sample chat application worked for me :). I used tomcat web socket implementation as the server and Jetty as the client. Are there any concise tutorials on usage of web sockets of Tomcat 8 ?